# Reference between aggregates with write model constraint

Tags: java, spring, jpa, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I know there are lots of questions talking about aggregates references here. But after reading some of them I still do not get an answer.

First I will describe my business logic.

I have two Entities:

`Resource` which describe the resource of a computation unit, including cpu, gpu, memory, disk. `Resource` can be used by users.

```java
class Resource {
  CPU cpu;
  GPU gpu;
  Memory memory;
  Disk disk;

  int totalCount; // The number of resource if limited
  boolean isAvailable; // Resource can be unavailable
  List<UserId> whiteLists; // Resource can give a white list where only limited users can use
}
```

`Plan` is a merchandise. It has a price and bind with a `Resource` and time.

```java
class Plan {
  String resourceId;
  Money price;
  int hours;
}
```

Right now I just save `resourceId` in `Plan` to follow the DDD principle: `Aggregates should reference other aggregates by Id`. But here is some business logic which make it quite difficult:

1. `Plan` should also follow the `Resource.whiteList`, it means that when a `Resource` is only accessful by some users then the `Plan` using this `Resource` should also follow this `whiteList`.
2. `Plan` should not be availabe if its `Resource` is not available.
3. `Plan` with the same `Resource` (but have different time) should follow some variants. For example, `Plan` with more time should always be expensive than the `Plan` with less time.

This three logic all means that `Plan` should always access `Plan.Resource`. And I think this is not just the [CQRS read model's logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480699/ddd-aggregate-design-referencing-between-aggregates) which only show the Plan and Resource together. It is necessary even in some `Plan` creation workflow.

So right now I think use `Resource` in `Plan` is quite necessary. But how to solve the conflict with the DDD principle, I just do not know how to explain this situation. Am I wrong to make them two separate aggregates? But the `Plan` and `Resource` do need to be editable separately.

### Update

There are some details I did not describe well.

1. The `Plan` will not be more than 100 during a very long lifecycle.
2. The `Plan` and `Resource` can only be edited by the administrator. There is no concurrency issue there. The `Plan` be bought buy users but users never edit it.
3. The `Plan` should always follow the `whiteList` in `Resource`, it is not acceptable that one user buy a `Plan` which he / she even have no rights to use the `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is used to hint the boundaries of the aggregate.
You can achieve the same effect by querying for the Resource before creating the Plan.
Reading at your validation rules that doesn't solve them, how do you know if the Resource is free in a given time?
You need to check all the Plans associated to that Resource to understand it.

Now there are 2 ways to solve for those invariants:
1.
Have a single aggregate Resource that has in in it a `List<Plan>`, and it takes care of creating them and can guarantee 100% consistencies of invariants.
2.
Have them separated, you create a Plan through some service that does some queries to check the status of the Resource and other Plans to ensure the invariants, and then create the new aggregate.

Solution 1 is hard to scale, the more Plan associated to a single Resource, more optimization you will need to have good performance.
Solution 2 allows for inconsistencies, it can happen that concurrent operations allow for two Plan to be created at the same time, or creating a Plan for a user that is concurrently removed from the whitelist.

Solution 1, what "good performance" means? How many plans will be there?
Solution 2 how much is the probability for concurrent writes to happen? Is that error rate acceptable? Can these issues being managed after it happens?

No general right answer, it depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So from your answer, the `Reference By Id` should be followed? I see the two solutions do not break it.

Comment: I see referencing the other aggregate with its id as more explicit in showing the aggregate boundary, forcing a query for the data of the Resource.

Comment: I have given some update for your questions